# string class relational operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

`p1` and `p2` point to the same string content, the following codes compare their addresses which are different.

```
const char *p1 = "abc";
const char p2[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
cout << (p1 == p2) << endl;                   // 0  (false)
```

But when I construct a string variable based on `p2`, then comparing `p1` and the string variable yields `1` instead of `0`.

```
string s1(p2);
cout << (p1 == s1) << endl;                  //  1  (true)
```

My question is : the string class has constructor that takes a `const char*` as its **only** argument, which tells the compiler to **convert** a `const char*` to string when possible:

```
string (const char* s);
```

Why doesn't the compiler convert `p2` to a temporary string variable, and then compare it to `p1` using the operator defined in string class:

```
bool operator== (const char*   lhs, const string& rhs);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because c++ can compare two `const char*` variable `p1` and `p2` (in other words, `p1==p2` is a valid c++ statement without any to string conversion), and the semantic is see whether they are the same physical address or not (in your example, they are not, and therefore a `false` is returned).

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't call that `operator==` overload because it can't - overload resolution for operators only kicks in if at least one of the types in the expression has class or enumeration type.

From C++11 draft n3290 §13.3.1.2 *Operator expressions*:

> If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to Clause 5.

(And clause 5 defines `==` in section §5.10, with the usual pointer comparison semantics among other things.)

So that overload is not even considered. You simply can't overload operators on only built-in types.